# Creating a document in Firestore using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After authenticating a user in my app I want to create a Cloud functions that creates a user profile document for them in my Firestore `userProfile` collection.

This is my entire `index.js` file for the cloud function:

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//function that triggers on user creation
//this function will create a user profile in firestore database
exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    // Do something after a new user account is created
    return admin.firestore().ref(`/userProfile/${event.data.uid}`).set({
        email: event.data.email
    });
});
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: admin.firestore(...).ref is not a function
    at exports.createProfile.functions.auth.user.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:13:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

In the Firestore cloud database I have a collection called `userProfile` where a document should be created with the unique id given to a user after authentication.

Comment: Looks good, run with it.

Comment: when i try that i get this error  admin.firestore().ref is not a function

Comment: Could you show your entire file of code and the entire error?

Comment: Added the entire error and file of code

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[admin.firestore()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) returns an instance of a [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/Firestore) object. As you can see from the API docs, the Firestore class doesn't have a ref() method.  You're probably confusing it with the Realtime Database API.

Firestore requires you to organize documents within collections. To reach into a document, you could do this:

```
const doc = admin.firestore().doc(`/userProfile/${event.data.uid}`)
```

Here, `doc` is a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/DocumentReference).  You can then set the contents of that document like this:

```
doc.set({ email: event.data.email })
```

Be sure to read the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) to understand how to set up Firestore - there are many places where it's different than Realtime Database.

Answer (score 21):

Here is my code. When I will create the new user below function will run.

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();


    exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

      var userObject = {
         displayName : user.displayName,
         email : user.email,
      };
  
      return admin.firestore().doc('users/'+user.uid).set(userObject);
     // or admin.firestore().doc('users').add(userObject); for auto generated ID 
 
    });
```

Comment: really clean code, thanks!  I wish the official Firebase docs were as easy to read as your code